# How to add the path variable in XCode 4.6 to use /usr/local/bin

Tags: xcode, path, scons

When compiling a project with an external build environment (scons) in XCode I run into the the issue that XCode can't find protoc which is in the /usr/local/bin directory.

sh: protoc: command not found

How can I add this path variable to sh / xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a shell script that adds the path locally and run this instead of the external build tool. This script first sets the path and flags and then later simply calls the external build environment scons.
Not pretty but works...

Comment: Or simply call `/usr/local/bin/protoc` rather than plain `protoc` from within the script?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to run into this periodically so about 6 months ago I began keeping an error journal so I wouldn't start from scratch trying to figure out what was wrong.

So for this I had two answers written down:

Change the Install Directory of the Library to $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) and change the Library Search Paths and the User Header Search Paths of the target to $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR (recursive)

I hope this does it for you, good luck.